# application.yml number property is changed

Tags: spring-boot

My application.yml looks like this:

```
test:
  icode: 0002
```

But when I get this value:

```
@Value("${baidu.icode}")
private String icode;
```

The `icode` field is 2.0, but I want it to be 0002, what should I do?

Comment: `@Value` doesn't work on `static` fields.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you! I have already delete static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make sure that your YAML properties will stay exactly the same, just wrap them in quotation marks:

```
test:
  icode: "0002"
```

Comment: @JuzerAli ah ok! I'm sorry I forgot.